# Spring boot configuration custom sql

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, oracle10g, spring-jdbc

I am trying to play with oracle edition views using spring data jpa and everything works fine.

The problem is if we can configure the specific oracle  views in spring boot. Is this possible and how?

Thanks for your help in advance.
Vicky

Comment: What is an "oracle editioning view" and why do you want to specify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very easy which I overlooked.. during the data source creaion we can pass the SQL that we need to trigger... This helped me load views..